# Finding all solutions $z=x+iy$ for four basic problems

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am preparing for an exam on Complex Analysis and I have four small problems. Two of them I think I have solved but I would really appreciate a sanity check since I very often miss something. On the other two, I have no idea how to start, any hint/suggestion would be appreciated. I need to find **all** solutions $z=x+iy$.

$\textbf{a) } z+1 = \log{(i+1)}$. The typesetting won't allow it, but is is actually Log, hence the principal branch.

$\begin{align}
z+1 &= \log{i+1}\\
z+1 &= \ln{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{4}\\
z &= \ln{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{4} -1
\end{align}
$

$\textbf{b) } \sin{z} = -i$. My solution is

$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} &= -i\\
e^{iz}-e^{-iz} &= 2\\
e^{iz}-e^{-iz} -2 &= 0 \text{ , now let $a = e^{iz}$}\\
a^{2}-2a-1 &= 0\\
a &= 1 \pm \sqrt{2}
e^{iz} = 1 \pm \sqrt{2}\\
iz &= \ln{(1 \pm \sqrt{2})}\\
z &= -i\ln{(1 \pm \sqrt{2})}.
\end{align}
$

Now the two problems I do not know where to start:

$\textbf{c) } (z+i)^{3} = 8. $ Writing it out does not seem to help me get anywhere, I then find $z^{3}-3z+3iz^{2}-i=8$.

$\textbf{d) } (z+1)^{2i} =1$. No clue.

Comment: for c, use roots of unity

Comment: Hint for c: let $z+i=Z$, now you have $Z^3=8$.  Get all possible values of $Z$ and subtract $i$ to get all possible values of $z$.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar but would you not end up with the same kind of equation I already have? You would still have to do $(x+iy)^{3}$, so how does that help?

Comment: @Steven See answer given by José Carlos Santos. Actually you will basically be getting $z+i=Z=2\cdot (1)^{1/3}$. I hope you are familiar with cube roots of unity. Else check [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) out.

Comment: If you have four questions, please make four different posts.  Why do you think it makes sense to post all of these together?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish because the approach and techniques/knowledge used to solve them seem to be very similar. I therefore thought combining them would make it more useful to other users...

Comment: @Steven I could get on board with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are correct.

**c**) $(z+i)^3=8\iff z+i=2\vee z+i=2\left(-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)$

**d**) I assume that $z^w$ is defined as $\exp\left(w\operatorname{Log}(z)\right)$. If so,\begin{align}(z+1)^{2i}=1&\iff\exp\left(2i\operatorname{Log}(z+1)\right)=1\\&\iff 2i\operatorname{Log}(z+1)=2\pi in\text{ (for some integer }n\text{)}\\&\iff\operatorname{Log}(z+1)=\pi n\\&\iff z+1=e^{\pi n}.\end{align}

Comment: I see how the trivial solution for c is $z+i =2 $, but how did you end up with the second part?

Comment: You should not provide complete solution to the homework-like problem in accordance with our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: @Steven I took the three cube roots of $1$ (which are $1$ and $-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$) and multiplied them by $2$.

Comment: @Doubtnut Am I wrong, or that's the homework policy of PSE? Anyway, I would not have answered if the OP has done nothing, but the OP solved other problems of the same type.

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't noticed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I really appreciate your solutions. But I do not fully grasp the idea of the unity root yet. What triggers you to find them and did you find them computationally or is it just standard knowledge that $-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ are cube roots of unity?

Comment: No! I used [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula). In this case, it tells me that the cube roots of $1$ are$$\cos(0)+\sin(0)i,\ \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)i\text{, and }\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}3\right)i.$$